# Why is the potential due to induced charges constant?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, conductors, boundary-conditions

Over the past few days, I have taken the time to read [this interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2175.pdf), where an unexpected counterexample is given that shows how the electrostatic force between a neutral metal conductor and a point charge can be repulsive in certain cases. On the fourth page of the paper, it is asserted that:

> the second equality follows from the fact that $\bar\phi_x(y) = \bar\phi_y(x)$ so that $\frac{q}{2} \nabla_x \bar\phi_x(x) = \mathbf{F(x)}$,

> where $\bar\phi_y(x) = \phi_y(x) + q \log |x - y|$  is the potential created by the induced charges on the metal object.

Now, I fully understand that because of Dirichlet's boundary conditions, $\phi_y(x) = \text{const.}$. But I'm struggling with $\bar\phi_x(y)=\bar\phi_y(x)$, which is not the same thing. If I am interpreting the notation correctly, $\bar\phi_y(x)$ is the potential at $x$ due to the induced charges when the point charge is at $y$. Why should that be the same as the potential at $y$ due to the induced charges when the point charge is at $x$, to the extent of saying (without obvious connection) $\frac{q}{2} \nabla_x \bar\phi_x(x) =-
\mathbf{F(x)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gauss's law for the point charge (eq. 3):
$$\nabla^2\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x) = 2\pi q\cdot\delta(\mathbf x - \mathbf y)$$
This is symmetrical in $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ since $\delta(\mathbf x)$ is an even function
$$\nabla^2\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = 2\pi q\cdot\delta(\mathbf y - \mathbf x) = 2\pi q\cdot\delta(\mathbf x-\mathbf y) = \nabla^2\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$$
Generally $\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y)$ can differ from $\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$ by a homogenous solution ($\nabla^2 \phi_h(\mathbf x) = 0$), but this addition is eliminated by the boundary conditions which uniquely define the potential, so:
$$\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$$

Therefore the induced potential is also symmetrical in $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$
$$\bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x) = \phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x) + q\ln|\mathbf x - \mathbf y|$$
and we get
$$\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$$

I'm not really sure what they do after that. Their definition of $\bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$ with the $\ln|\mathbf x - \mathbf y|$ term gives infinity when $\mathbf x = \mathbf y$, so their force $F(\mathbf y) = -q\nabla\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)|_{\mathbf y}$ is infinite, and so is the value for the potential energy of the system which they found as $U(\mathbf y) - U(\infty) = \frac q2\bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf y)$. Looks like they just ignored it lol

Edit: The factor of $\frac12$ in the force equation
$$\mathbf F(\mathbf x) = -\frac q2\nabla\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf x)$$
comes from the fact that they turned a function of 2 variables into a function of 1 variable. To simplify the explanation I'll go to 1 dimension ($\mathbf x\to x, \mathbf y \to y$). The potential function is normally a function of 2 variables:
$$\bar\phi_y(x)$$
but since it's always evaluated on the same position (they use it to find the force at point $y$ due to the point charge at $y$), it is more convenient to use a function of a single variable. This is created by parameterizing the 2 arguments $x(z) = z, y(z) = z$. This gives
$$\bar\Phi(z) \equiv \bar\phi_{y(z)}(x(z)) = \bar\phi_z(z)$$
Now to get the force as a function of 1 variable, the 2 variable function $F_y(x)$, which is the force at $x$ due to a point charge at $y$, is parameterized in the same way:
$$\mathrm F(z) \equiv F_{y(z)}(x(z)) = F_z(z) = -q\frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} = -q\frac{\partial\phi_y(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)}$$
The last thing they do is replace the derivative of the 2 variable potential function $\bar\phi_y(x)$ with the derivative of the single variable function $\bar\Phi(z)$. This is found using the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d\bar\Phi(z)}{\mathrm dz} &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \bar\phi_{y(z)}(x(z)) = \frac{\mathrm d x(z)}{\mathrm dz}\frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} + \frac{\mathrm d y(z)}{\mathrm dz}\frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(z,z)} \\
&= \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} + \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(z,z)}
\end{align*}

After the derivative is performed both $x$ and $y$ are being evaluated at $z$, so they are only dummy variables and can be renamed freely (I could call them $a$ and $b$, or $\mu$ and $\nu$, etc. It doesn't matter). So with that in mind, we use the relation $\bar\phi_y(x) = \bar\phi_x(y)$ on the 2nd term,
$$\frac{\mathrm d\bar\Phi(z)}{\mathrm dz} = \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} + \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{x}(y)}{\partial y}\bigg|_{(z,z)}$$
and then swap the names for the dummy variables $x$ and $y$ in the 2nd term, i.e. $(x,y)\to (y,x)$, which shows explicitly that both terms on the RHS are the same:
$$\frac{\mathrm d\bar\Phi(z)}{\mathrm dz} = \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} + \frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} = 2\frac{\partial \bar\phi_{y}(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)}$$
And this gives the relation we were looking for:
$$\frac{\partial\bar\phi_y(x)}{\partial x}\bigg|_{(z,z)} = \frac12\frac{\mathrm d\bar\Phi(z)}{\mathrm dz}$$
Finally this is substituted into the single variable force expression to get
$$\mathrm F(z) = -\frac q2 \frac{\mathrm d\bar\phi(z)}{\mathrm dz}$$
which is connected back to the notation of the original paper by replacing 1D positions and force with vectors (and renaming $z$ to $x$), single derivatives with gradients, and $\bar\Phi(z)$ with $\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf x)$:
$$\mathbf F(\mathbf x) = -\frac q2 \nabla \bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf x)$$
Just to be clear, I did the exact same math with the exact same functions as they did (besides 1D vs 3D) so this derivation exactly applies to the paper, I just used different notation to make things clear because at least for me most of the confusion came from reusing the same name for different things.

Comment: I cannot see why $\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$ should be true, but I cannot construct any counterexample. Is this symmetry evident, or maybe some standard result? I had read something about Green's Identities (or Green's Reciprocity Theorem), but I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: $\bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x) = \phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x) + q\ln|\mathbf x -\mathbf y|$ and $\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) + q\ln|\mathbf y -\mathbf x|$ by their definition. Since $\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$ as shown in my answer, and $q\ln|\mathbf y - \mathbf x| = q\ln|\mathbf x - \mathbf y|$ by evenness of the $|\mathbf x|$ function, we have $\bar\phi_{\mathbf x}(\mathbf y) = \bar\phi_{\mathbf y}(\mathbf x)$.

Comment: Thanks. One thing is not clear to me: how do we get from this equality to $\frac{q}{2}\nabla_x \bar\phi_x(x) =-\mathbf{F(x)}$?

Comment: @Bml It took me a lot of staring to figure out what they did and in my opinion its a less trivial result than their 1 sentence mention of it leads on lol. Anyway I edited my answer to explain how they got that force expression. Let me know if you have any questions.